# Google maps: points within a tolerance from a path

Tags: google-maps, distance, geodesic-sphere

I tried using the `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(position, path, tolerance)` function to decide whether the `position`(lat,lon) pair is within a certain distance (geodesic distance) from a designated path. The API says that the tolerance refers to measurements made in degrees, so one simple way of finding, let's say, points within a buffer radius of 50km from a certain path is to supply the *tolerance* as being 50/111 degrees (because one can assume that a degree corresponds to 111 km as the traveled distance on a sphere). Unfortunately, this is very erratic and gives many false positives even if they're 200 km away from the path. Am I misinterpreting what that function does?

Answer (score 0):

111km is the length of a longitudinal degree at zero latitude, but this distance is going to vary based on a few factors for different locations. What you need is a function that will calculate the distance (in degrees) between two LatLngs.

See the top answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908919/425834) for an example implementation.

Comment: That question computes the distance between two spherical vertices. There's no hint  whatsoever on how to compute the distance from a point to a spherical segment or a list of spherical segments.. and google maps already has this function embedded into it, it's not really useful for my purposes. What does the function mentioned in my post then really do? That's the more important question now. So, bottom line, I do not _need_ the distance function like you gave it..