# calculating distance in km from latitude and longitude to route google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have few people stand in between a route from Location A to Location B using google map api 3.

Now i want to find out which all people(we have their GPS coords) are near to that route.

How can i find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Geometry Library.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly

Static method `isLocationOnEdge()`

> Computes whether the given point lies on or near to a polyline, or the edge of a polygon, within a specified tolerance. Returns `true` when the difference between the latitude and longitude of the supplied point, and the closest point on the edge, is less than the tolerance. The tolerance defaults to 10<sup>-9</sup> degrees.

You have to include the library in your API call:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry
```

Comment: how tolerance and km are interrelated. Is there any mathematical formula

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908892/get-degrees-0-360-from-one-latlng-to-another-in-javascript/2908919#2908919